# Deleted python and tried to reinstall it using WSL but could not

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I recently started using the WSL and trying to put all my work on it since it will give me good knowledge on working with Linux. So, today I wanted to install python3 using the WSL and I noticed that I had the python on the windows previously. I tried uninstalling everything related to the python related to windows using the program files + command lines. After that I tried to install the python using the WSL and I could not install it due to this problem:
[image: here]

```
mansour@Mansour-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Mansour Al-Dossary$ **sudo apt-get install python3**

Reading package lists... Done 

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

The following additional packages will be installed:

  libpython3-stdlib python3-minimal python3.8 python3.8-minimal

Suggested packages:

  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv python3.8-venv python3.8-doc binutils binfmt-support

E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success

E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

I tried other methods to install the python but still did not work. When I deleted the python before, I made sure I deleted it safely without using windows interface to interrupt with the ubuntu programs files. Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: One option is compiling from source.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120544/error-while-installating-pip-for-python3) answer your question?

Comment: @tink
Thank you for your help. I was on a hurry so I what I did was deleting the WSL and the reinstall it. It appears that I deleted some files that have corrupted the apt or the ubuntu as whole(?). So, when I did reinstall it everything went smooth. I believe what you sent was going to solve my problem but right now I can't try it.

Comment: @Philippe it was solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, many core components of `apt` based distributions heavily rely on system-python.  So uninstalling that typically breaks things quite badly. I'm surprised that you got as far as you did!